# How to move values from one column to another based on matching values from other columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, database, merge

Example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Hopefully the attached image helps you understand what I'm going for.

I have 2 massive Excel files, one with `names` & `income` in the column next to them and another with *some* of the same names associated with other information.

How can I go about merging these data sets using the names as a key?

Comment: Use VLOOKUP, It iwll allow you to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **VLOOKUP** function to get the result:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$G$1:$H$7,2,FALSE)
```

[image]